# redirect back in wrong route in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

i use Laravel 6 for my project and for some of controllers i have to redirect back so when i use

```
 return redirect()->back();
```

in my project ,getting trouble and project redirect to

```
projectUrl/backRoute/favicon.png
```

automatically paste favicon.png to the end of the address also i use

```
php artisan route:clear
```

and check all route there is not any error in route i think something in framework change!
how can i fix it?

Comment: Try to use return redirect()->route('your.route.name')

Comment: try to use `return back();`

Comment: do you have your 'favicon' file being served by laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was found in icon link

```
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ asset('logoFile.png') }}">
```

type was not same exactly with icon extension and because of that project sometimes goings wrong